# php rest API POST request returning null

Tags: php, rest, return-value

I've created a `REST` API base on [this tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) - note that I am a newbie in `php` and `REST`...

Now, I am stuck when calling a `POST` request. The main return function is as follows:

```
// Requests from the same server don't have a HTTP_ORIGIN header
if (!array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}

try {
    $API = new MyAPI($_REQUEST['request'], $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    $res = $API->processAPI();
    echo $res;   // contains my json as expected
    return $res; // always empty string
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . json_encode(Array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

**EDIT**
I've just tried something even simpler in the API caller method, namely following:

```
try {
    $res = json_encode(Array('test' => "my message"));
    // comment out one or the other to check output...
    //echo $res;
    return $res;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: " . json_encode(Array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Result with `echo` is (the way I get responese is below... exact response is between # characters):

```
#{"test":"my message"}#
```

Result with `return` is

```
##
```

**EDIT 2**
Here is how I call the API from `C#`:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) { 
    JObject jo = new JObject();
    jo.Add("usr", "username");
    jo.Add("pwd", "password");
    Uri url = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", RestUrl, "login"));
    StringContent content = new StringContent(jo.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    bool isOk = response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    // this is where I get the result from...
    var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I really don't understand this - could someone please explain in non-php expert terms??

Comment: What do you do to receive response?

Comment: Can you please share your post form aswell.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information provided. Please show how you are visualizing the value of the return statement versus the echo statement. It would help if you showed more of your code.

Comment: @jjones I've put as much relevant information I could.... is there anything else I might be missing ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rest echo vs return in GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221651/rest-echo-vs-return-in-get)